# How to select item in Spinner to open a New Activity

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I'm trying to select an item in Spinner and that item will open an activity when I click the send button. For example, Activity 1 and Activity 2. In my spinner, I have Item 1 and Item 2. When I choose Item 1, I want Activity 1 to be open. 
 I've tried some code but it doesn't working. 
 Here's my code.

Spinner in activity_main.xml

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        android:entries="@array/punpColleges"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

In my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    private static Button button_send;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnClickButtonListener();
    }
    public void OnClickButtonListener() {

        button_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button_send.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        if (spin.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("CCS")) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class));
                        } else {
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondTesting.class));
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

}
```

Strings are located in strings.xml

```
<string-array name="punpColleges">
        <item>CCS</item>
        <item>CBE</item>
    </string-array>
```

I also added this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ListActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Post your code for spinner

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? and move `spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);` line after calling `setContentView ` method

Comment: When I run my application in smartphone, it doesn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't initialize your spinner at class level. It has to be done after calling `setContentView`. `findViewById` can't be used unless you have set the layout to the activity.

Define the spinner like this

```
Spinner spin;
```

Add

```
spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
             this, 
             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
             getResources().getStringArray(R.array.punpColleges));
spin.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

inside `onCreate` after calling `setContentView`

Comment: if block looks good to me. You need to update your code the way I have suggested.

Comment: @YuiMisakiSakura: Perfect. Don't forget to accept the answer then please

Comment: Answer Accepted. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

On button click try this to call your Activity

```
try {
        myClass = Class.forName("com.example.yourPackageName." + classComplete); //classcomplete as your file name, take it from spinner selected object
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, myClass);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define Spinner and Variable to store position of spinner

```
int x=0;
Spinner spin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
         android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
         list);
spin.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                   View view, int position, long id) {
                                                x=position;
 });
}
```

Now compare the postion on Button click

```
if(x==0)
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, myClass1);
    startActivity(myIntent);
else
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, myClass2);
    startActivity(myIntent);
```